# Hiding the searchbar till the user swipes it down for iOS 7

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uisearchbar, ios7

I have added the searchbar to the tableHeaderView of the tableview. However, writing

```
self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 44);
```

**or**

```
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
```

Hides the searchBar behind the navigation bar at the top but its not visible even when the user swipes the tableview down. It hides again. This seems to work fine in iOS 6 but not in iOS 7 beta. What do I need to do?

Comment: iOS 7 is currently under NDA, so you are not allowed to discuss it in public forums. Because of this, you probably won't get an answer. Just so you know.

Comment: Where can I post it as a question then?

Comment: You could try the [Apple Developer Forums](https://devforums.apple.com).

Comment: I have the exact same problem with my app, can we talk about it yet? Or did you find a solution? I am also missing the table header row, that slides under the Nav bar too! :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed it by putting ..

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

in the `viewWillAppear`, it needs a check for iOS 7 before executing, as it is a new method introduced in iOS7.

Plasma